# Eclipse - How do I publish non-Java resources without a web.xml file?

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, tomcat

My WebApp uses Java annotations to map the URL to the servlet (@WebServlet) and I don't have a *web.xml* file. I want to foward the request to another HTML file and I did it like so:

> request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/test/testpage.html").forward(request, response);

It works, but I can't get additional resources (javascript) from the server.

> <script type="text/javascript" src="testsuite.js"></script>

testsuite.js is located in /WEB-INF/test/testsuite.js, the same folder as testpage.html. When requesting testsuite.js I get 404. How can I configure Tomcat to serve all the resources in my work tree without a web.xml? Worst case I will simply embed JS.

Additionally I let eclipse install the web server on my local machine so I have no idea how they are deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to move resources outside of your `WEB-INF` folder. It is a special folder for compiled Java code, jars, configuration files etc.

The `WEB-INF` folder is restricted in application servers and servlet containers for security reasons, so for example a request for `/appname/WEB-INF/web.xml` will be deined of course.

Static resources such as `*.html` files, `*.css` files, `*.js` files, images etc. should be placed outside of `WEB-INF` folder, in your case the `test` folder should be moved up next to `WEB-INF`.